# How to use a filtered `keyof this` in a TypeScript class member function?

Tags: typescript

Here is some code which I'd like to do:

1. A class with a few member fields and functions;
2. This class provides a function called `callMe`;
3. The parameter of the `callMe` would be limited only to be one of the member names of this class;
4. Only the name of member fields are acceptable and name of member functions should be excluded.

The strange things are:

1. If I call the `callMe` function with an instance everything goes fine as expection.
2. However, if I call the `callMe` in a member function of this class there would be an error.

Details below:

```js
// I'd like to use this `Filter` to get all the non-function field names of a type
type Filter<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? never : K }[keyof T] & string;

class BaseClass {
  // This function should only accept a parameter which only matches the non-function member names
  public callMe<V extends Filter<this>>(param: V) {}
}

class MyClass extends BaseClass {
  // These member field should be involved
  public stringField: string = '';
  public numberField: number = 0;
  public booleanField: boolean = false;
  // These member functions should be excluded
  public shouldBeExclude() {}
  public test() {
    // this line is error:
    // TS2345: Argument of type string is not assignable to parameter of type Filter<this>
    // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'this[keyof this] extends Function ? never : keyof this'
    this.callMe('stringField');
  }
}

const instance = new MyClass();
// However these lines work as expected
instance.callMe('stringField'); // Valid
instance.callMe('numberField'); // Valid
instance.callMe('shouldBeExclude'); // Invalid: TS2345: Argument of type 'shouldBeExclude' is not assignable to parameter of type Filter<MyClass>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEkHIBNQGwJYGsCmoAuB7UBXAzmugBYJ6gAGAYgnOigE7kbYDmK6oAhnHBkWgDtMAgLQAzHAIDG6BMNBiEKOLAGcAtijKYxXDAE8ADigBQ6I2mq0GAHgAqAPlABeUAG9QAbQDSoBANBUfR1QOwBdAC5QnzDQFAAPOgFoMkpJGTkAgH5QARQANwZQKN8AX08gkPDQADJQPHR6fxYAbhMTKThOPDIAIW6UAGEunvcTUFAQUJIyCWlZeTwiTBwVUGE4fS4pKRRDDk5QQ056DXYigHcSKSJ1gU3QdU50G60+QWFxdIWAzXUAIyKak0eHGRxw-0QUlAUm4cAAsigbAA1OKJFDJVI0Oj0GzEUgOBwACmOp3UUWRAEp3KUTLSOiMyPD9MNumQEkkUqB+gRWaM3GCpnZ+ARHigAUVFMpYEsVmtAX4BPlMHBCtAwYYIVD6o1mtRpVEGk0BCwXKBIJA2hNNZCENCBDgJfR9Soog6nWaAAxW8G26H-TAqlCcAQu6BRANBkNmsTcAg+oUitB-QH0BTfTJkWWrWAKhKdHDQFDq61au31ZY53ooACi8QLRaJ1LctNLfowWnQTbGEwmU3xZEQeT87Po9Ew9AiYL7YDsAGUAEwAZgALABWKIAQXoLEdGI4IXMxh1xtNpFymAOPQQLDUkMI2FJZxx610R8s2NsA4c08ms4s5pGs0kAjheV54Ded5wA+BjHpAA4VCgwRvjMsQchiXJpPMmSgDkeSFGmUSVChpCQL+A4AHSwjwiJEpAQEmmGkCUj6tL0lIwgNIqDQhrsZp5BcoDMnyeBNm0UwABKYBcBRFMQWhoEObwXBOSBcOy8TGDIxYmP4PHSCgVFwrR9G6oxSgqMxLR-qAyLcAg6p6egvGGdRCIoHR7qpkxLE2XZiCOQI+m7EZNEefRlYqNWdYNigVk2eASr2eGoSLquG6gNuu6aAIB5vgBEVytA0X1nAhZxaBQjgZBnD3swRwnM+RSHgBVg4jYwmMj+QA)

How can I make the `Filter` works with the member function `test`?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for your comment. I updated the post to move the `callMe` function into a base class, which was my original intention.

Comment: The problem is that `Filter<this>` is a generic conditional type (`this` is implicitly a generic type param and `Filter` uses a conditional type), and the compiler cannot perform the higher reasoning necessary to conclude that `'stringField'` is assignable to it.  It mostly just gives up and cannot verify that much of anything at all is assignable.  In cases like this you'll be happier widening `this` to `MyClass` before calling `callMe`, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mpKlpN). Does that fully address the question? If so, I'll write up an answer explaining? If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz The widening seems good to my issue. Can these statements to be simplier? Or could it be auto inferred instead of explicit typing it out?

Comment: Which statements? Simpler in which way?  I'm not sure if you're asking for a clarification, a modification to my suggestion, or a followup question (which would be out of scope here).  ... it seems you're editing your comment.  Could *what* be auto inferred?

Comment: As the walk around you mentioned above now I could write code as `(this as MyClass).callMe`.  I want to know if  this `as MyClass` could be simplified, or to be wrappred in certain way. Otherwise I have to repeat this as statement in lots of member functions.

Comment: If it could be auto-inferred then you wouldn't have the problem you're having now.  Note that `as MyClass` is less safe than a type annotation as well.  I'm not sure how to proceed here.  Shall I write up my answer and you can post a followup question if you want to seek optimizations? Or should you [edit] the question with further requirements for how "simple" the solution needs to be (keeping in mind that the answer might be "this is now overconstrained and therefore impossible).  Please let me know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript on its own can't really do much about it, instead i'd suggest you to pass an explicit type to the parent class via generics. This way you will automatically have correct type checking in all of your methods at once:

```
// I'd like to use this `Filter` to get all the non-function field names of a type
type Filter<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? never : K }[keyof T] & string;

class BaseClass<Child> { // here we add a generic type
  public callMe<V extends Filter<Child>>(param: V) { }
}

class MyClass extends BaseClass<MyClass> {
  // These member field should be involved
  public stringField: string = '';
  public numberField: number = 0;
  public booleanField: boolean = false;
  // These member functions should be excluded
  public shouldBeExclude() { }
  public test() {
    this.callMe('stringField');  // Is valid now
  }
}

const instance = new MyClass();
instance.callMe('stringField'); // Valid
instance.callMe('numberField'); // Valid
instance.callMe('shouldBeExclude'); // Invalid: TS2345: Argument of type 'shouldBeExclude' is not assignable to parameter of type Filter<MyClass>
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEkHIBNQGwJYGsCmoAuB7UBXAzmugBYJ6gAGAYgnOigE7kbYDmK6oAhnHBkWgDtMAgLQAzHAIDG6BMNBiEKOLAGcAtijKYxXDAE8ADigBQ6I2mq0GAHgAqAPlABeUAG9QAbQDSoBANBUfR1QOwBdAC5QnzDQFAAPOgFoMkpJGTkAgH5QARQANwZQKN8AX08gkPDQADJQPHR6fxYAbhMTKThOPDIAIW6UAGEunptBkhUnDxBQfno0AHc0TmhYTlA2PKapA2MTUFBDHAAjRB2pbjgAWRQbADU4xJRk1Jo6ejGJ6AcHAApDTj0DRRO4ASncoFKJihHRGZCu%20mG3TICSSKVA-QISNGCOxeCm%201AMzs-AIoE06mORUUylgeCImBwKlAVL8AnymDghWghKOpwQOwaTQELGotKiQuaLlAkEgbQOfLOuRwlIYYpUUQEKqp9GlAAZ5YcTkrjphOShOAJ1dAoqbzZbpWJuARDcTSWgKTqFOlZMIyPTGczWQlOjhoCgeQrjQL6gymdBeigAKLxUPh37gjxQqP8nZ0BoZ9yEg7EUgAOguPBuv0gkpF1sgoJaBxm4DI%20W4CFUmAWhKhMKkfo4-galqkaFceQWoFxcIzbRH6DHKArl2rtcazQbTaJYDunZ5i%20Xq6rKBrWtV9G3zZm%208Qh4Eo%20kK8r1zPtbjKkTKbTKEbN7AcB2QPKI7AAZQAJgAZgAFgAViiABBegWBVZ4OBCcxjBlAN42-VM4DDP8-DIIQOGRBAWDUU5CGwAEgU0d5QEwixQCsd4bFnZEHBMIA)

Comment: Wow. Pass the child class to the base as a generic type does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `this` in not an interface (or statically known type), so it fails to be instantiated properly

> An interface can only extend an object type or intersection of object types with statically known members.(2312)
> - the definition of interface in error message

You have two choices:

- to cast to interface:  `(this as MyClass).callMe('stringField');`
- to declare this to be an interface:  `public test(this: MyClass) {`

```
class MyClass extends BaseClass {
  // These member field should be involved
  public stringField: string = '';
  public numberField: number = 0;
  public booleanField: boolean = false;
  // These member functions should be excluded
  public shouldBeExclude() { }

  public test1() {
    (this as MyClass).callMe('stringField');
  }
  public test2(this: MyClass) {
    this.callMe('stringField');
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd like to use `callMe` in a property setter. How can I add the `this:MyClass` to a property setter?

Comment: @jayatubi plz code

Comment: I tried add `this` to a property setter such as `set bar(this: Producer, value: string) {...}` but get an error `TS2784: get and set accessors cannot declare this parameters.`

Comment: @jayatubi then you can use `(this as MyClass)` cast (or as `let c: MyClass = this`) I guess